# iframe not displaying at all on chrome and safari. It works on firefox

Tags: php, html, iframe

I really don't know why but when I try to display an iFrame into google chrome and safari it don't work.

The pure source code in chrome looks like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/uqfY3xnv6sE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>        <form name="submitForm" method="get" action="myPage.php">
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="url"/>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I 'inspect element' in chrome, the result is that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="560" height="349" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>        <form name="submitForm" method="get" action="myPage.php">
            <label>
                <input type="text" name="url">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit">
        </form>
</body></html>
```

Notice that there is absolutely no "src" in "inspect element". Firefox does display the iframe.

Comment: Did you try with a strict doctype?

Comment: I just tried and it does not work.

Comment: It's working for me (Chrome and FF, OSX 10.7). If you are acessing the file locally (with file:///), try on a webserver (with http://)

Comment: I'm working on a local server. I jsut tried my code on another page... and it works... I really don't understand what is going on.

Comment: @bfavaretto Works for me in Chrome using a local `file:///` path. Jean-Philippe, do you have any browser extensions enabled in Chrome and Safari? AdBlock for example

Comment: Not sure why your __iframe__ isn't loading. Try changing the allowfullscreen attribute to allowfullscreen="true". Also, make sure there aren't any fancy quotes hiding in there.